# The size cannot change after del the build depends

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a dockerfile as follow, and find that the size of dcoker image can't reduce when I add the "RUN apk del .build-deps",

```
RUN apk -U upgrade && \
    apk -v add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc make && \
    apk -v add --no-cache bash curl && \
    apk -v add --no-cache mysql-client libc-dev mariadb-dev
COPY ./squid.conf /etc/squid/
COPY ./startService.sh /

WORKDIR /home/mysql_auth
RUN make clean && make && make install
RUN apk del .build-deps && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

what is wrong, and Can I modify something in this Dockerfile to reduce the docker image size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way that docker images are built out of layers. A good explanation that applies to your case can be found at [this post.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1755)

The general technique is to link together all of the things you want to have committed in one layer into a single RUN command. In your case it might look something like this (will likely need tweaking):

```
RUN apk -U upgrade && \
    apk -v add --no-cache bash curl && \
    apk -v add --no-cache mysql-client libc-dev mariadb-dev
COPY ./squid.conf /etc/squid/
COPY ./startService.sh /

WORKDIR /home/mysql_auth
RUN apk -v add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc make && \
    make clean && make && make install && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```